# Showing application version on grafana dashboard

Tags: monitoring, grafana

I want to show application (which is monitored) on grafana dashboard. How can I do that?

Can I expose some REST interface with version and consumes it in Grafana?
Should I install some plugins to grafana (if yes which?)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hey @Piotr you can show whatever you need, as long there is a way to access it for grafana. If there is no version data in your monitoring endpoinz, you should extend it. What tech stack your app is made on?

Comment: @ibexit Thanks for answer. I have java and spring. I expose version of app via REST service, but I don't know how to consume it by grafana. Do you have some examples how to consume and show info from REST (json) service?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the fastest option will be to use the Text panel with HTML where you code in JS what you need (API call). Of course, API must be always available from any Grafana. JS in text panel POC: https://community.grafana.com/t/rss-feeds-news-feeds/10597/2